# Replace Div with another Div

Tags: jquery, html, swap

I have this thing I m trying to do. I have a main picture of a map and within that map there are regions. These regions have hot spots on them so you can click them and it will replace the whole map with only the region. (just a simple `div` swap).

I need it as a `div` because in this `div` i have the hot spots listed.

There are a total of 4 `div`s that I am going to need to do this with.

If anyone could help me that would be awesome!

So links that are listed in a table need to replace the image in a separate `div`.

```
<tr class="thumb"></tr>
<td>All Regions (shows main map) (link)</td>
</tr>

<tr class="thumb"></tr>
<td>Northern Region (link)</td>
</tr>

<tr class="thumb"></tr>
<td>Southern Region (link)</td>
</tr>

<tr class="thumb"></tr>
<td>Eastern Region (link)</td>
</tr>
</table>


<div>All Regions image</div>
<div>northern image</div>
<div>southern image</div>
<div>Eastern image</div>
```

I am not allowed to post images because I don't have enough points so I know the image links wont work.

Comment: i think you should add a bit of you code

Comment: @jake - welcome to Stackoverflow. I have a suggestion for you. It's better if you can show some codes. Like where is the problem -or what have you gone through so far. That way the one who would like to answer can also give you a better answer. ;) cheers!

Comment: Sweet as thanks man ill do an edit now. Thanks heaps for your help and support guys! Ill update it now!

Comment: So pretty much all the regions should be displayed only 1 at a time, on page load load up the all regions image then when you click on the link it changes to the relevant picture for it.

Comment: Is this code sufficient?

Comment: That table wont change at all as it will be a refference to view other maps when you click on that link.

Comment: @experimentx, thanks for your help man i have created this link
http://jsfiddle.net/KNbQZ/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use [**`.replaceWith()`**](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```js
$(function() {

  $(".region").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $(this).html();
    $('#map').replaceWith('<div class="region">' + content + '</div>');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="map">
  <div class="region"><a href="link1">region1</a></div>
  <div class="region"><a href="link2">region2</a></div>
  <div class="region"><a href="link3">region3</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well i need a link to change a complete seperate Div rather than the text its self. So click the link and the link stays the same but the images change between them

Comment: yeah this is pretty much what im after, but  rather than the links be hidden have the images. So there is a constant list of region names. When you click the region name it changes the image in the div. I put some code in my original questing as for the structure that i am looking for. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

**HTML**

```html
<div id="replaceMe">i need to be replaced</div>
<div id="iamReplacement">i am replacement</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
jQuery('#replaceMe').replaceWith(jQuery('#iamReplacement'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This [should](http://jsfiddle.net/KNbQZ/14/) help you

HTML

```
<!-- pretty much i just need to click a link within the regions table and it changes to the neccesary div. -->

<table>
<tr class="thumb"></tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="showall">All Regions</a> (shows main map) (link)</td>   

<tr class="thumb"></tr>
<td>Northern Region (link)</td>
</tr>

<tr class="thumb"></tr>
<td>Southern Region (link)</td>
</tr>

<tr class="thumb"></tr>
<td>Eastern Region (link)</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />

<div id="mainmapplace">
    <div id="mainmap">
        All Regions image
    </div>
</div>
<div id="region">
    <div class="replace">northern image</div>
    <div class="replace">southern image</div>
    <div class="replace">Eastern image</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var originalmap;
var flag = false;

$(function (){

    $(".replace").click(function(){
            flag = true;
            originalmap = $('#mainmap');
            $('#mainmap').replaceWith($(this));
        });

    $('.showall').click(
        function(){
            if(flag == true){
                $('#region').append($('#mainmapplace .replace'));                
                $('#mainmapplace').children().remove();
                $('#mainmapplace').append($(originalmap));
                //$('#mapplace').append();
            }
        }
    )

})
```

CSS

```
#mainmapplace{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

#region div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```