# Removing the div child in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace Div with another Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062916/replace-div-with-another-div)

```
<div id='test'>
 <span></span>
 <p></p>
 <button></button>
 <h1></h1>
</div>
```

**My question is** , how we can remove the `button`  element and insert someother on the same position in jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
   $('#test button').replaceWith('<span>new</span>')
```

Comment: please add more text or details

Answer (score 2):

`$('#test button:first').replaceWith('<span>new</span>')`

Answer (score 1):

you can use`replaceWith()` method:

```
$('#test button').replaceWith('<p>another element</p>')
```

Comment: this replaces all `button`s on the page

Comment: selector can be altered, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.replaceWith()` method to accomplish this. For [more](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
$('#test').find('button').replaceWith('<input type="text"/>');
 alert($('#test').html());
```